# Can I calculate a half-zero data's FFT from its non-zero front part's FFT?

Tags: dft

I have data whose latter half are all-zero. For example, `data=[a, b, c, d, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, and `front_half=[a, b, c, d]`. Is there any way to obtain *FFT(data)*, by some compute-efficient transform on the *FFT(front_half)*?

I made some work on the equations. The even items in *FFT(data)* are just equal with *FFT(front_half)*. But the odd items in *FFT(data)* seems twisted with dot-multiply with a time-domain weight vector, which looks hard to be calculated from the *FFT(front_half)*.

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/21927/4298) could be helpful.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/efficient-fft-computation-of-a-zero-padded-vector

Answer (score 2):

The computationally efficient way is to do an IFFT/zero-pad/FFT.  It's usually less efficient to do a circular Sinc interpolation (to create the effect of a rectangular window in the other domain) for any large number of extra points.  Any other interpolation is less accurate.

Answer (score 2):

There are no really noteworthy savings here: for a half-zero data set, only the first butterfly operation is trivial and can be replaced by a copy over the zeroed elements.  Everything afterwards is business as usual.  So you can have something like 9*512 butterfly operations rather than 10*512 butterflies, a saving of 10%.  With larger transforms, the savings make for an even smaller percentage.